# Iterator to Map (CvBlobs) always points to other place C++

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator, tracking

I have a class called BlobTracking that uses the cvBlob library to extract blobs from a blob mask.
I call the function cvb::cvLabel(&segmentated, labelImg, blobs); The blobs are stored in the class variable cvb::CvBlobs blobs (already tried to put the variable public and private)
(definition of CvBlobs:  typedef std::map CvBlobs;)

I have another class called OF_Object. In the class BlobTracking I have stored OF_Objects:
    Blobtracking.h

```
struct VectInfo {
   OF_Object oF_Object;
   int index;
   int size;
};
typedef std::map<OF_ID,VectInfo> OF_Objects;
class BlobTracking
{
private:
    OF_Objects oF_Objects; ...
}
```

When on the function process of the blob tracking class, in one of the OF_Objects I call the function

I'm calling blobOfPoint from the BlobTracking class and all the 3 variables of blobOfPoint are private variables from the BlobTracking class.

The problem is when in the function blobOfPoint, when I'm debugging on Xcode, I see the variable blobs and has for example one element. But the iterator bi=blobs.begin(); points to somewhere else.

I put here the function blobOfPoint and also the process of the BlobTracking and I make a note in the line were the blobOfPoint is called.
I also post a print screen showing the xCode debugging:

Print screen of value of variable blobs:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26082578/SS01.png

Print screen of value of variable iterator bi=blobs.begin():
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26082578/SS02.png

```
bool OF_Object::blobOfPoint(Point2f &point,cvb::CvBlobs &blobs, BlobPolygons &blobPolygons)
        {
        bool found= false;
        if(oF_BlobsFP.size()>0)
        {
            OF_BlobsFP::iterator it=oF_BlobsFP.begin();
            while(!(found = poinInBlob(point,*blobs.find(it->first)->second,blobPolygons)) && it!=oF_BlobsFP.end())
                it++;
        }
```

The problem is in this iterator here as you can see in the print Screens of Xcode!!

```
        cvb::CvBlobs::iterator bi=blobs.begin(); 
        cvb::CvBlob test=*bi->second;
        if(!found)
        {
            while(!(found = poinInBlob(point,*bi->second,blobPolygons)) && bi!=blobs.end())
                bi++;
        }

        if(found)
        {
            OF_BlobsFP::iterator it = oF_BlobsFP.find(bi->first);
            //If doesn't exist
            if(it==oF_BlobsFP.end())
            {
            oF_BlobsFP.insert(std::pair<cvb::CvLabel,vector<Point2f> >(bi->first, vector<Point2f>()));
                it = oF_BlobsFP.find(bi->first);
            }
            it->second.push_back(point);

        }
        return found;
    }
```

Process in Blob tracking

```
void BlobTracking::process(const cv::Mat &prevInput, cv::Mat &img_input, const cv::Mat &img_mask, cv::Mat &img_output)
{
if(img_input.empty() || img_mask.empty())
    return;

cv::Mat mask(img_input.size(), CV_8UC1);

IplImage segmentated =IplImage(img_mask);

IplConvKernel* morphKernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5, 5, 1, 1, CV_SHAPE_RECT, NULL);
cvMorphologyEx(&segmentated, &segmentated, NULL, morphKernel, CV_MOP_OPEN, 1);

if(showBlobMask)
    cvShowImage("Blob Mask", &segmentated);

IplImage* labelImg = cvCreateImage(img_input.size(), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);

unsigned int result = cvb::cvLabel(&segmentated, labelImg, blobs);

//cvb::cvFilterByArea(blobs, 500, 1000000);
cvb::cvFilterByArea(blobs, minArea, maxArea);
blobPolygons.clear();
cvb::CvBlobs::iterator bi=blobs.begin();
while(bi!=blobs.end())
{
    blobPolygons.insert(std::pair<cvb::CvLabel,cvb::CvContourPolygon *>(bi->first,cvb::cvConvertChainCodesToPolygon(&bi->second->contour)));
    bi++;
}

nBlobs=blobs.size();
if(nBlobs=0)
    oF_Objects.clear();
else{
    //If there are objects
    if(points[0].size()>0&&oF_Objects.size()>0)
    {
        //Compute optical Flow
        calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevInput, img_input, points[0], points[1], status, err, winSize,3, termcrit, 0);
        objOfBlobs.clear();
        OF_Objects::iterator it=oF_Objects.begin();
        int i=0;
        //Associate each point of each object with a Blob
        while(it!=oF_Objects.end())
        {
            it->second.oF_Object.clearOF_BlobsFP();
            int index=it->second.index;
            int oldSize=it->second.size;
            it->second.index=i;
            int nPointsWithoutBlob=0, newSize=0;
            while(oldSize>0)
            {
                //If point calculated and is inside of a Blob
```

The function is called here:

```
                if(status[index]&&it->second.oF_Object.blobOfPoint(points[1][index],blobs,blobPolygons)){
                    points[0][i] = points[1][index];
                    newSize++;
                    i++;
                    //circle(img_input, points[1][i], 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8);
                }
                oldSize--;
                index ++;
            }
            it->second.oF_Object.setnPointsWithoutBlob(nPointsWithoutBlob);
            it->second.size=newSize;

            //Update new objects to see which ones finished,which ones had a significant increase in size and which ones splitted
            if(!it->second.oF_Object.updateOF_Object(blobs))
                oF_Objects.erase(it);
            else
            {
                //Add the information to which blob(s) is the object associated
                OF_ID oF_ID=it->second.oF_Object.getID();
                //If not splitted just add the first blob in the list
                if(!it->second.oF_Object.splitStatus())
                {
                    cvb::CvLabel bLabel= it->second.oF_Object.getBlobLabel();
                    std::map<cvb::CvLabel,vector<OF_ID> >::iterator it2 = objOfBlobs.find(bLabel);
                    if(it2==objOfBlobs.end())
                    {
                        objOfBlobs.insert(std::pair<cvb::CvLabel,vector<OF_ID> >(bLabel, vector<OF_ID>()));
                        it2 = objOfBlobs.find(bLabel);
                    }
                    it2->second.push_back(oF_ID);

                }
                else{
                    //If splitted, add all objects in the list
                    OF_BlobsFP::iterator it3 =it->second.oF_Object.getOF_BlobsFP().begin();
                    while(it3!=it->second.oF_Object.getOF_BlobsFP().end())
                    {
                        cvb::CvLabel bLabel= it3->first;
                        std::map<cvb::CvLabel,vector<OF_ID> >::iterator it4 = objOfBlobs.find(bLabel);
                        if(it4==objOfBlobs.end())
                        {
                            objOfBlobs.insert(std::pair<cvb::CvLabel,vector<OF_ID> >(bLabel, vector<OF_ID>()));
                            it4 = objOfBlobs.find(bLabel);
                        }
                        it4->second.push_back(oF_ID);
                        it3++;

                    }
                }


            }
            it++;
        }
        points[1].resize(i);
        points[0].resize(i);

        //Check Merged Blobs
        std::map<cvb::CvLabel,vector<OF_ID> >::iterator it5 = objOfBlobs.begin();
        while(it5!=objOfBlobs.end())
        {
            if(int s=it5->second.size()>0)
            {
                int i=0;
                while(s>0)
                {
                    OF_ID oF_ID=it5->second.at(i);
                    OF_Object *pOF=&(oF_Objects.find(oF_ID)->second.oF_Object);
                    pOF->setMergeStatus(true);
                    pOF->setUpdateStatus(false);
                    i++;
                    s--;
                }
            }
            it5++;
        }

        //Check for objects to recalculate new features
        it=oF_Objects.begin();
        std::set<OF_ID> ofToUpdate;
        while(it!=oF_Objects.end())
        {
            if(it->second.oF_Object.getUpdateStatus()){
                if(it->second.oF_Object.newFeatures(blobs, img_input))
                    ofToUpdate.insert(it->first);
                it->second.oF_Object.setUpdateStatus(false);

            }
            it++;
        }
        //if there were objects with new features, copy not updated points to a new vector and add new ones to the end
        if(ofToUpdate.size()>0){
            it=oF_Objects.begin();
            int k=0;
            while(it!=oF_Objects.end())
            {
                //if object not with new features
                if(ofToUpdate.find(it->first)==ofToUpdate.end())
                {
                    int index=it->second.index;
                    int size=it->second.size;
                    it->second.index=k;
                    while(size>0)
                    {
                            points[1][k] = points[0][index];
                            k++;
                            size--;
                            index ++;
                    }
                }
                it++;
            }
            points[1].resize(k);
            points[0].resize(k);
            swap(points[1], points[0]);
            std::set<OF_ID>::iterator it5 = ofToUpdate.begin();
            while(it5!=ofToUpdate.end())
            {
                OF_ID ofId=*it5;
                oF_Objects.find(ofId)->second.index=k;
                vector<Point2f> &oF_Points =  oF_Objects.find(ofId)->second.oF_Object.getOF_BlobsFP().begin()->second;
                int size=oF_Points.size();
                oF_Objects.find(ofId)->second.size=size;
                int i=0;
                while(size>0)
                {
                    points[0].push_back(oF_Points[i]);
                    i++;
                    k++;
                    size--;
                }
                it5++;
            }


        }
    }
}

//Check for blobs without OF_Objects and create new objects for them
cvb::CvBlobs::iterator it = blobs.begin();
int k=points[0].size();
while(it!=blobs.end())
      {
          if(objOfBlobs.find(it->first)==objOfBlobs.end())
             {
                 OF_Object objct = OF_Object(img_input,it->first,blobs,last_OF_ID);
                 last_OF_ID++;
                 VectInfo vctInfo= {.oF_Object=objct,.index=k,.size=objct.getNTFeatures()};
                 oF_Objects.insert(std::pair<OF_ID,VectInfo >(objct.getID(), vctInfo));

                 vector<Point2f> &oF_Points =  objct.getOF_BlobsFP().begin()->second;
                 int size=objct.getNTFeatures();
                 int i=0;
                 while(size>0)
                 {
                     points[0].push_back(oF_Points[i]);
                     i++;
                     k++;
                     size--;
                 }
             }
          it++;
      }

//    if(!blobs.empty()){
//        for(std::map<cvb::CvLabel,cvb::CvBlob*>::iterator it = blobs.begin() ; it != blobs.end(); it++)
//        {
//            //std::cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << std::endl;
//            cvb::CvID id = (*it).first;
//            cvb::CvBlob* blob = (*it).second;
//            createMask(mask, *blob);
//        }
//    }
if(drawFeatures)
{
    for(int m=0;m<points[0].size();m++)
    {
        circle(img_output, points[0][m], 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8);

    }
}
cvReleaseImage(&labelImg);
cvReleaseStructuringElement(&morphKernel);

firstTime = false;
}
```

Comment: waaa, wall of code. could you cut it down to a *minimal* example ?

Comment: I put it all the code of function just in case but please just refer to the line after "The function is called here:"

Comment: I edited to make the question more clear.
Basically the problem is the iterator bi=blobs.begin() that doesn't point to the first element of blobs as it was supposed. Please check the print screens

Comment: OF stays for open frameworks? also, you're using old C API. also, do you know that in the last opencv versions there is a `cv::SimpleBlobDetector`?

Comment: Sorry but what do you means with "OF stays for open frameworks?"
I didn't know about the SimpleBlobDetector but my deadline to finish this is tomorrow so I need to use what I have now

Comment: OF *means*, you're using the OpenFrameworks libs ?

Comment: but nkint is quite right there, the combination of c-api and CvBlobs (both horribly outdated) was a bad choice right from the beginning.

Comment: No, of means Optical Flow.

Comment: As I said my deadline is tomorrow so now I don't have time to change all the project. But I would really need help in the problem with the iterator because my project doesn't work due to that so I'm completely stuck. This is for a thesis to present tomorrow :<

Comment: I think I found the problem...
Is in the header of the function that receives the files as references. The position of the "&"...

bool OF_Object::blobOfPoint(Point2f &point,cvb::CvBlobs &blobs, BlobPolygons &blobPolygons)
Needs to be changed to

bool OF_Object::blobOfPoint(Point2f& point,cvb::CvBlobs& blobs, BlobPolygons& blobPolygons)
Just this small detail gave me such an headache :/